# Newtonsoft.Json De-Serialization does not override a property set in constructor

Tags: c#, json.net

### Context

I have a class to be serialized and de-serialized with Newtonsoft.Json.

My idea is to set default values to some fields in the constructor, so during the de-serialization, if a value is missing, the default is assumed.
However, for my surprise, the deserializer won't replace the default value with the value in the JSON string.

### Code

```
public class MyClass {

    public int Key { get; set; }

    private void LoadDefaults() {
        Key = 1;
    }

    public MyClass() {
        LoadDefaults();
    }
}
```

After serializing an instance from the class above, I get this JSON:

```
{    "Key": 2    }
```

Then I de-serialize it using this:

```
public void Deserialize(Stream input, out MyClass output) {
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(input)) {
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr)) {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            output = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jr);
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the deserializer to call first the constructor of "MyClass" which in turn calls LoadDefaults();
Everything seems to happen as expected. But then, after the constructor finishes, I am expecting the deserializer
to replace the default value of Key=1 (set inside the constructor) with the value deserialized from the JSON string which is 2.
The problem is that the property Key of the deserialized object "output" has a value 1 instead of 2.

Why is that happening?
Do the de-serializer skip non null properties after constructing the object?

### Online example (.NET Fiddle)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/P5GguD

Comment: Why not used `MyClass output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);` ?

Comment: Looks like `serializer.Deserialize` does not set the explicit properties. If you remove `Key = 1;` from inside the constructor., it will display `0`. Not sure why though..

Comment: `JsonTextReader` doesn't actually work there, the class is not deserialized, so you create a new class object with values set in the constructor. Use `var textStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonMC));` (UTF-8 is the default, not UTF16-LE). Or specify the Encoding explicitly: `using (var sr = new StreamReader(textStream, Encoding.Unicode))`

Comment: Note that, in deserialization, you can specify, e.g., `[DefaultValue(1)][JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)] public int Key { get; set; }`. If the Key property is missing in the JSON string, the default value (`1`) will be set. -> In the previous comment, `jsonMC` is a copy/paste error, your original string is named just `json` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed out providing the encoding type in StreamReader. As a result the stream was not built properly.

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(textStream,Encoding.Unicode)) //Provide encoding as Unicode
{
    using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
    {
        var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        output = serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(jr);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am quite shocked I made that mistake in the demo. However the original real life code, does not have the encoding error. And if I erase the LoadDefault() call from the constructor, the class is properly de-serialized and populated with the values from JSON. So there is a bug there, and when creating the demo, I accidentally generated the same behavior but with a different bug. So your answer is correct for my question. However I just noticed I continue with the problem in my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Deserialized it directly, why do you need to set it in StreamReader? You can deserialize it directly using the JSON string value return by serialize.

```
var mc = new MyClass(){Key = 2};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mc);

Console.WriteLine("Serialized Key is: " + mc.Key);

MyClass output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
        
Console.WriteLine("De-serialized Key is: " + output.Key);
```